Tools to identify the cyclomatic complexity of GLSL code
In principle, cyclomatic complexity is a quantitative measure of the number of linearly independent paths through the source code of a program.
I am forced to keep the cyclomatic complexity of our GLSL shader code below 20.
Are there tools that can determine the cyclomatic complexity from the source code (GLSL)?
It is not permissible for me to determine it by hand. I have the requirement to use a tool that is executed before each check-in to the repository.
